# Remove AdView from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am currently dealing with In-App purchases in my app which has ads in many different views but when somebody purchases the *remove ads* I want to remove ads. This is what I am doing now:

There are `FBAdView` in each class header
and then I go to where I want to remove it.

`PurchaseViewController.m`

In the interface:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) RVModelViewController *modelViewController;
@property (copy, nonatomic) RVExportViewController *exportViewController;
```

then we initialize it:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _modelViewController = [[RVModelViewController alloc] init];
        _exportViewController = [[RVExportViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `removeAds` method:

```
 - (IBAction)removeAds:(UIButton *)sender {

        // banner ads
        FBAdView *banner1 = self.adView;
        FbAdView*banner2 = _modelViewController.adView

        // interstitial ads
        FBAdView *int1 = self.adView2;

        [banner1 removeFromSuperview];


         // Banner 2 cant be removed as it is in another class
        [banner2 removeFromSuperview];


       [int1 removeFromSuperview];
      }
```

Can you please help me, I am fairly new to iOS programming.. I have no idea how I can change UI from another class.

Answer (score 0):

The design must account for the (pretty common) case where a view controller whose appearance/behavior you want to affect has not yet been created.

To achieve this, the app should remember a user preference, and, on something like `viewWillAppear` in each view controller, if the user's preference (ad-free) is set, then call your `removeAds` code.  This might be a good candidate for code to put in a common superclass of all of your view controllers.